# Full Calendar event time adding an hour on chrome and safari browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am using  Jquery fullcalendar 3.3.1 & moment.js 2.15.1. to show the event calendar and on event click, it shows the modal popup with event details. Events details are stored in SQL database and using ajax to populate the events using web method EventList.aspx/GetEvents.

Everything is working as expected except that the event time shows 1 hour ahead in Chrome & Safari browser. I am using moment.js to format the Date & time as

```
$('#msDate').html(moment.utc(calEvent.start).local().format('DD-MM-YYYYHH:mm'));
```

Calendar code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      data: "{}",
      url: '<%= ResolveUrl("EventList.aspx/GetEvents")%>',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#fullcal').fullCalendar({
          eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#eid').html(calEvent.id);
            $('#modalTitle').html(calEvent.title);
            $('#msDate').html(moment.utc(calEvent.start).local().format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'));
            $('#meDate').html(moment.utc(calEvent.end).local().format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'));
            $('#mloc').html(calEvent.loc)
            $('#mdesc').html(calEvent.des)
            $('#url').attr('href', 'Meetings/Meeting.aspx?ID=' + calEvent.id)
            $('#fullCalModal').modal();
          },
          header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
          },
          views: {
            month: { // name of view

              columnFormat: 'ddd',
            },
            week: { // name of view
              titleFormat: 'MMMM  D , YYYY',
              columnFormat: 'ddd D/M',
            },
            day: { // name of view
              titleFormat: 'MMMM  DD  YYYY',
              columnFormat: 'ddd D-M-YYYY',
            }
          },
          displayEventTime: false, // hide event time 
          eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
          events: $.map(data.d, function(item, i) {
            var event = new Object();
            event.id = item.EventID;
            event.title = item.EventName;
            event.start = new Date(item.StartDate);
            event.end = new Date(item.EndDate);
            event.loc = item.Location;
            event.des = item.Description;
            return event;
          }),
        });
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Web method returns records in SP :

```
1111    ABCD    2017-10-20T09:30:00 2017-10-20T16:30:00 xxx
```

JSON data as :

```
EndDate:"2017-10-20T16:30:00"
EventID:1111
EventName:"ABCD"
Location:"xxx"
StartDate:"2017-10-20T09:30:00"
```

converting DateTime using

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),m.StartDate,126) AS startdate inside the SP.
```

Modal popup shows:

```
starttime:20-10-2017 10:30  endtime:20-10-2017 17:30
```

Comment: You must date setting on sql

Comment: what do you mean by You must date setting on SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** Thanks to @ADyson for pointing out I was wrong about Fullcalendar not accepting native Javascript Date objects.  I've removed that part of my answer and elaborated on the 2nd part, which is the real problem.

This is a bit tricky.  `moment.utc(somedate)` tells Moment that `somedate` *is* a UTC date, rather than a local date (which it would otherwise assume).  It does not convert the date to UTC, it simply flags it as *already in* UTC.

```
var local = '2017-10-20T09:30:00',              // Local timestamp
    m = new moment(local),                      // Moment representing local time
    a = moment.utc(local),                      // Specify that 'local' is UTC
    b = m.utc();                                // Generate UTC time from local

console.log('local', local);                    // 2017-10-20T09:30:00
console.log('m', m.format());                   // 2017-10-20T09:30:00+02:00
console.log('a', a.format());                   // 2017-10-20T09:30:00Z
console.log('b', b.format());                   // 2017-10-20T07:30:00Z
```

The "Z" in the results indicate UTC timestamps.  But note for `a`, the time has not changed, it is still the local time, just incorrectly flagged as being UTC.  If you then use `a.local()`, you switch it to local time, but since it already is local, it will be off by your local offset from UTC:

```
console.log('a.local()', a.local().format());   // 2017-10-20T11:30:00+02:00
console.log('b.local()', b.local().format());   // 2017-10-20T09:30:00+02:00
```

(The `a.local()` result shown is for my local timezone, UTC+2.  Since your results are off by 1 hour, you must be in UTC+1, and you will see `2017-10-20T10:30:00+01:00`).

So in your `eventClick()`, you don't need any utc/local flags or modification to display the timestamp, just use your formatting:

```
$('#msDate').html(calEvent.start.format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'));
```

As a side note, note that the date strings in your JSON are already suitable for Fullcalendar - a string like `2017-10-20T09:30:00` should work fine, so there's no need to generate a Date from it, simply using:

```
event.start = item.StartDate;
```

in your `$.map()` should work fine.

Comment: The docs for "Moment-ish" at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/ say "...most options that accept a Moment will also conveniently accept anything that the moment() constructor accepts, including:

date strings (ISO8601 is highly recommended), 
unix offsets (milliseconds since the Unix Epoch), 
**native Date object**" so I don't think passing in JS dates in itself should be a problem, although I do agree in this case it's a bit redundant.

Comment: Wow, thanks @ADyson, I had no idea.  You are quite right, thanks for correcting me.  I've updated my answer, removed that part of it and elaborated on the 2nd part which is the real issue.

Comment: Thanks, folks. I have used the same code in the beginning and all of a sudden time started to change on different browsers. Finally, I have managed to work the time issue on chrome, IE, Firefox & Safari browser. Tested and all working.   $('#msDate').html(moment(calEvent.start).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'));